# Is it possibile in DRF to write object based validation and field based validation in the same serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-validation

Is it possible to write a serializer like this?

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['password'] != data['password_confirmation']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Passwords doesen't match")
        return data

    def validate_password(self, value):
        if (len(value) < 8):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Password must be at least 8 characters")
        return value

    def validate_email(self, value):
        lower_email = value.lower()
        if CustomUser.objects.filter(email__iexact=lower_email).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This email already exists in our database")
        return lower_email
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'uid'] * uid firebase localId
```

It is calling the `validate_email` and `validate_password` but it's not calling the `validate` method. In the view i'm calling the `is_valid()` method.
I'm wondering if it's possible to use both of these validations.

Comment: Maybe I'm crazy..but this looks completely valid. You should be able to call both field and class validation methods like this. Are you sure the `validate()` method is not being called for valid cases?

Comment: Hi @rob, thanks for you time, yes i tried to raise the validate() exception but it doesen't work. I also tried to print on the very first line of it but with no luck.

Comment: are you defining a `Meta` for this where you define the associated model? As it stands you have no field for `password_confirmation`. I believe you might have issues using `ModelSerializer` without defining a `model` in your `meta` subclass.

Comment: I'll update the question with the complete class

Comment: Have you tried using the validation methods after the meta class? I mean below the meta class?